# postgres IN clause not using index

Tags: postgresql

When I am using IN, the query is not using index and scanning mview on which view1 is built. But same query when = is used, uses index and returns fast. How to make IN use index and complete fast.

Here its using "=" clause

```
explain analyze select * from schema1.view1 cr 
    where c_cd = (select distinct c_cd from schema1.mview1 where cd = 'XY87296C');
Subquery Scan on res  (cost=110.44..110.52 rows=1 width=271) (actual time=0.130..0.139 rows=5 loops=1)
  Filter: (res.rnk = 1)
  InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
    ->  Unique  (cost=60.80..60.90 rows=20 width=6) (actual time=0.041..0.045 rows=1 loops=1)
          ->  Sort  (cost=60.80..60.85 rows=20 width=6) (actual time=0.041..0.042 rows=3 loops=1)
                Sort Key: mview1.c_cd
                Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
                ->  Index Scan using ix_cd_n on mview1  (cost=0.43..60.37 rows=20 width=6) (actual time=0.030..0.034 rows=3 loops=1)
                      Index Cond: ((cd)::text = 'XY87296C'::text)
  ->  WindowAgg  (cost=49.53..49.59 rows=2 width=1287) (actual time=0.128..0.134 rows=5 loops=1)
        ->  Sort  (cost=49.53..49.54 rows=2 width=271) (actual time=0.119..0.120 rows=5 loops=1)
              Sort Key: cerer.rer_cd, cerer.r_dt DESC, cerer.rere_dt DESC, cerer.rere1_dt DESC
              Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 27kB
              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.84..49.52 rows=2 width=271) (actual time=0.101..0.107 rows=5 loops=1)
                    Join Filter: (cerer.r_dt = mx.r_dt)
                    ->  Index Scan using ix_c_cd on cerer cerer  (cost=0.42..24.51 rows=5 width=271) (actual time=0.069..0.070 rows=5 loops=1)
                          Index Cond: ((c_cd)::text = ($0)::text)
                    ->  Materialize  (cost=0.42..24.66 rows=5 width=13) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=1 loops=5)
                          ->  Subquery Scan on mx  (cost=0.42..24.63 rows=5 width=13) (actual time=0.026..0.027 rows=1 loops=1)
                                ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=0.42..24.58 rows=5 width=13) (actual time=0.026..0.026 rows=1 loops=1)
                                      Group Key: cerer.c_cd
                                      ->  Index Scan using ix_c_cd on cerer  (cost=0.42..24.51 rows=5 width=13) (actual time=0.011..0.018 rows=5 loops=1)
                                            Index Cond: ((c_cd)::text = ($0)::text)
Planning Time: 0.812 ms
Execution Time: 0.471 ms
```

Here its using IN clause

```
explain analyze select * from schema1.view1 cr 
    where c_cd in (select distinct c_cd from schema1.mview1 where cd = 'XY87296C');
Merge Join  (cost=74280.97..74345.71 rows=1 width=271) (actual time=1415.760..1415.861 rows=5 loops=1)
  Merge Cond: ((res.c_cd)::text = (mview1.c_cd)::text)
  ->  Subquery Scan on res  (cost=74220.16..74284.52 rows=8 width=271) (actual time=1214.729..1395.978 rows=144485 loops=1)
        Filter: (res.rnk = 1)
        Rows Removed by Filter: 534
        ->  WindowAgg  (cost=74220.16..74264.41 rows=1609 width=1287) (actual time=1214.726..1383.997 rows=145019 loops=1)
              ->  Sort  (cost=74220.16..74224.19 rows=1609 width=271) (actual time=1214.706..1239.776 rows=145020 loops=1)
                    Sort Key: cerer.c_cd, cerer.rer_cd, cerer.r_dt DESC, cerer.rere_dt DESC, cerer.rere1_dt DESC
                    Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 111598kB
                    ->  Gather  (cost=40122.36..74134.47 rows=1609 width=271) (actual time=308.210..409.188 rows=205422 loops=1)
                          Workers Planned: 2
                          Workers Launched: 2
                          ->  Hash Join  (cost=39122.36..72973.57 rows=670 width=271) (actual time=301.493..400.779 rows=68474 loops=3)
                                Hash Cond: (((cerer.c_cd)::text = (mx.c_cd)::text) AND (cerer.r_dt = mx.r_dt))
                                ->  Parallel Seq Scan on cerer cerer  (cost=0.00..33147.12 rows=134112 width=271) (actual time=0.004..20.591 rows=107290 loops=3)
                                ->  Hash  (cost=38055.93..38055.93 rows=71095 width=13) (actual time=300.894..300.896 rows=108049 loops=3)
                                      Buckets: 131072  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 6089kB
                                      ->  Subquery Scan on mx  (cost=36634.04..38055.93 rows=71095 width=13) (actual time=246.132..278.589 rows=108049 loops=3)
                                            ->  HashAggregate  (cost=36634.04..37344.99 rows=71095 width=13) (actual time=246.130..269.294 rows=108049 loops=3)
                                                  Group Key: cerer.c_cd
                                                  ->  Seq Scan on cerer  (cost=0.00..35024.69 rows=321869 width=13) (actual time=0.019..60.328 rows=321869 loops=3)
  ->  Unique  (cost=60.80..60.90 rows=20 width=6) (actual time=0.056..0.060 rows=1 loops=1)
        ->  Sort  (cost=60.80..60.85 rows=20 width=6) (actual time=0.055..0.057 rows=3 loops=1)
              Sort Key: mview1.c_cd
              Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
              ->  Index Scan using ix_consume_customer_health_coverage_cd_n on mview1  (cost=0.43..60.37 rows=20 width=6) (actual time=0.040..0.045 rows=3 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: ((cd)::text = 'XY87296C'::text)
Planning Time: 0.770 ms
Execution Time: 1424.928 ms
```

Comment: Are your statistics up to date? The planner thinks it will find rows=1609 but in reality it is rows=205422. Some other steps in your query plan have the same issues.

Comment: using `EXISTS(...)` will probably yield the same plan as the scalar subquery. [BTW: `DISTINCT` in a query is almost always a red flag ...] [BTW2: your scalar subquery is uncorrelated, so it could be moved to the main query IMHO]